# Stream a file from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, weed-fs

I am using [weed-fs](https://github.com/cruzrr/node-weedfs) to store files and trying to stream file to client using below code

```
var fileName = [__dirname, '/uploads/', req.params.id, ".png"].join('');

try {
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
    weedfs.read(req.params.id, writeStream);
    writeStream.on("close", function () {
        var readStream = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
        response.pipe(readStream);
        response.on('error', function (err) {
            readStream.end();
        });
        response.on('end', function (err) {
            removeFile(fileName);
        });
    });

} catch (e) {
    res.send(404);
}
```

But I am getting error `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED`

If I look at the `weedfs` read method, I found below code

```
read: function(fid, stream, cb) {
    var ins = this;
    if ((typeof stream == "function") && !cb) {
        cb     = stream;
        stream = false;
    }

    this.find(fid, function(pub) {
        if (pub[0]) {
            if (stream) {
                ins.http(pub[0]).pipe(stream);
        ......
```

Am I doing something wrong. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Perhaps the server wasn't running or at least not at the address you attempted to connect to.

Comment: @DanD. But still it is not sending response. Response goes into timeout mode.